# Is there a possibility for two different primes to have any of its powers to be the same?

Tags: prime-numbers

Say there are two primes $P_1$ and $P_2$ where $P_1 \neq P_2$. Is there a possibility for some $m$, $n$ ($m \neq 0, n \neq 0$) such that $P_1^m = P_2^n$.

Comment: If two numbers are equal, then their prime factorisations are the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.  Because then $P_1$ divides both sides.  And if a prime divides a product of terms, it must divide at least one of the terms.  In particular, it must divide $P_2$, contradicting that $P_2$ is distinct.

Comment: Sorry for my silliness. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Strictly speaking this does happen.  For example, in the integers $P_1 = 3$ and $P_2 = -3$ are both prime, and clearly $P_1 \neq P_2$. Yet $P_1^2 = P_2^2$, and the same is true for any even power.

What's going on is that primes $P_1$ and $P_2$ while not equal are *associates*, i.e. one is a unit multiple of the other (a unit being an invertible ring element, -1 in this case).  Since it is possible for a unit raised to a power to equal 1, so too is what the Question describes.